# Jenkins Disable CLI over Remoting via a Groovy Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-cli

Is is possible to disable Jenkins CLI over Remoting option via Groovy script? I want to put the script into init.groovy.d so that is option is disabled upon start up so I am not prompted to disable it

Thanks

Comment: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/234709648-Disable-Jenkins-CLI

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can do it like this (jenkins2.60.2)

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getDescriptor("jenkins.CLI").get().setEnabled(false)
```

Regards

Comment: if you want to save it in a file add:
 
    Jenkins.instance.save()

Answer (score 8):

Create the file `$JENKINS_HOME/jenkins.CLI.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jenkins.CLI>
  <enabled>false</enabled>
</jenkins.CLI>
```

It will behave as if you pressed the "Disable Jenkins CLI over Remoting" button in the Jenkins GUI once the server restarts.

juhnz's answer covers disabling the CLI completely. However, I believe the intent of the question was just disable the Jenkins CLI over remoting, only, but otherwise enable the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions, create file \init.groovy.d:

```
import jenkins.*;
import jenkins.model.*;
import hudson.model.*;

def protocols = AgentProtocol.all()
for (protocol in protocols) { 
  if (protocol.name.contains("CLI")) {
    protocols.remove(protocol)
  }
}

def disableAccess(def list) { 
  for (extension in list) { 
    if (extension.getClass().name.contains("CLIAction")) {
       list.remove(extension)
    } 
  }
}

def instance = Jenkins.instance;
disableAccess(instance.getExtensionList(RootAction.class))
disableAccess(instance.actions)
```